# Passport's 'req.user' becomes undefined sometimes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, passport.js

I am using passport for authorization and I am saving the session in mongodb using 'connect-mongo-session' module. I noticed that after sometime when I try to login the req.user object becomes undefined, although the session object is present in the database and passport and session details are present in the req object. Here is my session setup:

```
let store;

if(env === "development")
    store =  new MongoDBStore({  //Allows session to be stored and retreived even when server restarts.
  uri: config.db,
  collection: 'mySessions'
  })

else {
   store =  new MongoDBStore({  //Allows session to be stored and retreived even when server restarts.
  uri: config.db,
  collection: 'Cosmos'
  })
}

  app.use(session({
    store: store,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.app.sessionSecret
  }));

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

and here is the code responsible for serializing and :

```
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// Use Passport's 'deserializeUser' method to load the user document
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findOne({
        _id: id
    }, '-password -salt', (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing saveUninitialized to false and resave to false, so it looks like this now:

```
    app.use(session({
      store: store,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 84, // I added this just in case
      resave: false,
      secret: config.app.sessionSecret
  }));
```